# Why is my first array item still there if I put a condition where it must be shown only when nothing is in the array?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView where if nothing is in it, a "NEW" item is shown. The problem is that the "NEW" item is shown even if there are more elements in the array. Ideas?

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        nume = null;
        prenume = null;
        nume_list event_nou = new nume_list(nou, addClassmate);
        if (colegi_list.isEmpty()) {
            colegi_list.add(event_nou);

        }
    } else {
        nume = extras.getString("NumeFam");
        prenume = extras.getString("Prenume");
        String nume_complet = prenume + " " + nume;
        nume_list colegNou = new nume_list(nume_complet, "");
        if (prenume != null && nume!=null) {
            colegi_list.add(colegNou);
        }

        nume_list colegNouv2 = new nume_list(prenume, "");
        if (nume==null) {
            colegi_list.add(colegNouv2);
        }

    }
} else {

    nume = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("NumeFam");
    prenume = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Prenume");
}
```

The button from the other activity:

```
backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("Prenume", prenumeString);
                extras.putString("NumeFam", numeFamString);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ColegInfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent1, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ColegInfoActivity.this).toBundle());


            }
```

PS: when the button is pressed it goes to the other activity where the data should be included in a new item. There is every time a new item (that's ok) but the NEW is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by Now is still there, please try to make yourself more clear

Comment: After I add an event (or more) the NEW is still there with the new items.

Comment: What do you mean by NEW ?

Comment: "new" is the item which should be included when no item is in the list. It's like showing " New, create an item!"

Comment: Can you please make it clear the definition?

Comment: So, I will recap. There is a page where details should be completed in some EditTexts. From there, the data is loaded to the MainActivity, where the ListView is. The ListView should show "NEW" with a specific description when no created items are on the list. When an item is created from the data from the EditTexts, "New" should disappear. The problem is that it still is there.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you said ' "new" is the item which should be included when no item is in the list. It's like showing " New, create an item!" ', so you have to delete this element when you add to the list or the list is going to keep new.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    nume = null;
    prenume = null;
    nume_list event_nou = new nume_list(nou, addClassmate);
    if (colegi_list.isEmpty()) {
        colegi_list.add(event_nou);

    }
} else {
     colegi_list.remove(0); //as NEW is on 0 index
    nume = extras.getString("NumeFam");
    prenume = extras.getString("Prenume");
    String nume_complet = prenume + " " + nume;
    nume_list colegNou = new nume_list(nume_complet, "");
    if (prenume != null && nume!=null) {
        colegi_list.add(colegNou);
    }

    nume_list colegNouv2 = new nume_list(prenume, "");
    if (nume==null) {
        colegi_list.add(colegNouv2);
    }

}
```

} else {

```
nume = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("NumeFam");
prenume = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Prenume");
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you find it useful, mark it as an answer to help future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your information somewhere else in the code like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("StringKeyForBoolean", false);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("StringKeyForDouble", 3.4);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("StringKeyForInteger", 5);
    savedInstanceState.putString("StringKey", "Folio3/blog");
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem.